# Django how to manage format time with only hour and minute

Tags: python, django, datetime

In django form, I would like an input for a time with a format only with hour and minutes.
 But I keep having second on my web page.
Anyone could help
Thank you

models.py

```
Class Recettes(models.Model) :
    …
    temps_preparation = models.TimeField(
            db_column='Temps_Preparation',
            help_text = 'veuillez saisir le temps sous la forme heure:minute(HH:MM)',
            blank=True,
         null=True,
            ) 
….
```

settings.py

```
...
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = [ '%I:%M']
```

forms.py

```
class RecetteForm(forms.ModelForm) :
    temps_préparation = TimeField(input_formats = ['%H:%M',], label='Temps de préparation – HH:MM')
```

Comment: Try django template filter for date https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Comment: try a lot of template filter for time but I always get a time with second whatever I'm doing

Comment: Hi I found my mistake. In my sql database, I use varchar type instead of Time type for my time field. As far as I modify the type, everything's going find.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a single line to the `settings.py` file and it will change the time formatting across all the apps in your project.

add this to the `settings.py` file:

- If you want the 12 Hr clock formatting with AM/PM:  `TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%I:%M %p',)`
- If you want 24 Hour clock formatting: `TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%H:%M',)`

Answer (score 1):

in setting.py add

`'DATETIME_FORMAT': "%m-%d - %M:%S"`

in models.py

`temps_preparation =  models.DateTimeField(null=True)`

and in form.py

`datetime.strptime(yourdate, "%M:%S")`

Answer (score 0):

You can format dates directly in the html template ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date))

```
<p>{{ your_date|date:"h:iA" }}</p>
```

or in the view ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html))

```
your_date.strftime("%I:%M%p")
```

In the example above I used the 12-hours format.

Comment: I try in the html templates <p> {{my_time|time : "h:i" }} </p> and i Get a template syntax error - Could not parse the remainder: ' : "h:i"' from 'recette.temps_preparation|time : "h:i"'

Comment: You need to remove all spaces when you are using template filters: try with {{my_time|time:"h:i" }}

Answer (score 0):

Using TimeField and setting seconds to 00 before

See: [TimeField Model in Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.1/ref/models/fields/#timefield)